# Initializing a filter in Grails

Tags: grails

I'm running Grails 2.3.3 and have introduced a filter:

```
class HvFilters {

   def HvLoginDetailsService

   def filters = {
      all(controller:'*', action:'*') {
         before = {
         }
         after = { Map model ->
            model.myLoginDetails = HvLoginDetailsService.myLoginDetails()
         }
      }
   }
}
```

When I build using a run-app I get this error:

```
2018-02-01 15:54:38,710 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - 
Error initializing the application: Method on class [homevu1.HvFilters] was 
used outside of a Grails application.
```

I've looked at various posts etc. regarding this GrailsContextLoader error - all signs point to the need to initialize the filter in Bootstrap - I had a go but still getting the same error:

```
SpringSecurityUtils.clientRegisterFilter(
'HvFilters', SecurityFilterPosition.PRE_AUTH_FILTER.order)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the fix for this is, but it definitely has nothing to do with `SpringSecurityUtils.clientRegisterFilter`. This is a method in the spring-security-core plugin to insert a servlet filter into the security filter chain. It's not a generic helper method for servlet filters, and since Grails filters are _not_ servlet filters (they're backed by Spring `HandlerInterceptor`s) it's entirely the wrong approach.

Comment: All the posts I've seen say that this error GrailsContextLoader error is a result of the class not being initiated and recommend doing this in the Bootstrap . I just haven't been able to find the exact syntax I need to init a filter .